# Orchard - Query Custom Fields in Content Item

Tags: orchardcms, custom-fields

I have a Content Type "News" with custom field "NewsDate" (DateTimeField) and "Active" (BooleanField)

Now I'm need to get 3 active atimes order desc by NewsDate

Get all news, make them toList() and from there manipulate the data is not a solution.

P.S. I need to do something like:

```
        var items = contentManager
            .Query(Entities[PageType.Press])
            .OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord, DateTime?>(record => record.PublishedUtc)
            .Slice(0, 3);
```

but instead of PublishedUTC use my custom field "NewsDate" and add Active == true, However it is not possible due to Orchard architecture of storing custom data in a separate field as XML data.

**UPDATED:**
In a nutshell I want to generate from code behind the following Query:

```
DECLARE @temp as TABLE(id int, xmldata xml)
INSERT @temp VALUES(1,'<Data><News><NewsDate>07/14/2011 11:42:00</NewsDate><Link Title="" DisplayText="" Link="www.example.com" OpenInNewTab="True">www.example.com</Link></News></Data>')
INSERT @temp VALUES(2,'<Data><News><NewsDate>07/11/2011 12:11:00</NewsDate><Link Title="" DisplayText="" Link="www.example.com" OpenInNewTab="True">www.example.com</Link></News></Data>')
INSERT @temp VALUES(3,'<Data><News><NewsDate>02/21/2012 16:56:00</NewsDate><Link Title="" DisplayText="" Link="www.example.com" OpenInNewTab="True">www.example.com</Link><NewsLink></NewsLink></News></Data>')

SELECT  
 TOP 3 [id],
[xmldata].value('(Data/News/NewsDate)[1]', 'datetime') as NewsDate
FROM @temp
ORDER BY NewsDate DESC
```

P.S. I looked through the code for DynamicContentQueryTests, however all the examples uses the Part, and in my case Fields are just in the ContentItem:
E.g. News content type contains NewsDate field (datetime field) and some parts as well

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying fields is possible since 1.4 through Projector and underlying index tables and new APIs on Content Manager. Your simplest bet actually may be to create a projection.

Comment: To be honest, I found no info in google and other blogs how to work with Projector in code. Everything I found was to create widgets in admin area.

Comment: They are content items, so it shouldn't be very different from working with other content items in code...

Comment: Could I please ask you to give me an example how to check the Field and order by that field? or point me to a documentation section where that is discussed? or just give direction what module in code should I examine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, why Data column is nvarchar(max) for contentItem, not xmldata? Please see updates for my question. And thanks a lot for helping me with that.

Comment: That last question is an easy one: xmldata is a SQL Server type that may not exist on other databases. Using anything proprietary would cut us from compatibility with other database engines. Your other questions are more complex and will require some research on your part. A projection is a content item that you can build from code. Look at the parts involved in the type and go from there.

Comment: Yes it does. It belongs to a part that has the same name as the type.

Comment: That is interesting, let me add thar contentItem News was created from the dashboard (without code involved) and it is just content item with added NewsDate (date time field) also from the dashboard. So in code behind I have no News type actually...

Comment: That's fine: you don't need a type, and more often than not there isn't one. It doesn't prevent the dynamic implementation of ContentItem or Projector from finding it.

Comment: This article describes in detail how to query content items by content fields using HQL: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/querying-orchard-fields-with-hql

Answer (score 3):

To get the values of fields that have been attached directly to a Content Item, you need to first look for the Content Part with the same name as the item, which is created by Orchard. So in your case in the `Parts` list for each News Content Item you'll find a part called "NewsPart", and inside this the `Fields` property will have your `NewsDate` and `Active` fields.

However, like you say Orchard serializes the field values into XML for storage to prevent it having to change the database structure every time you add/remove a field to/from a content type. For this reason, querying and ordering by fields is not recommended because all the serialized data needs to be de-serialized for each Content Item. If you want to be able to do this, the best way is to make your own Content Part with a Content Part Record and use your own table for storage, then you can do this:

`contentManager.Query<NewsPart, NewsPartRecord>()...`

...and query/sort on whatever values you like.

Comment: I agree with you on my own PartRecords, however we have likt 6-8 entities that are differ in one field like News, Events, Testmonials, etc... And I don't think it worth to create almost the same records for just quering.

Answer (score 0):

Bertrand is correct. Check this link : http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/projector-module-in-orchard-cms. You can implement your requirements easily with Projection Module. The link will tell you the steps to do that. If you don't want a widget, you can create a page with your query too. Once the module is enabled, you will see the option to create a Projection Page in the left hand side navigation.

[image]

EDIT :

Can't you simply parse the XML? You can query your content type 'News'. Something like -
`var contentItems = contentManager.Query<ContentPart>("News").Join<TitlePartRecord>().Join<AutoroutePartRecord>().Join<CommonPartRecord>().List();`

Once you have that, you can access the XML data by  :

```
foreach (var item in contentItems)
  {
    var contentItem = (ContentItem)item.ContentItem;
    ContentItemVersionRecord contentItemRecord = contentItem.VersionRecord; 
    string data = contentItemRecord.Data; 
    //Call some function here to parse 'data' and store the object in the list. 
  }
```

'data' has the information in XML format that you need.
You can parse it and then store the objects in your list that you can order by your custom field.

Comment: Please check the question, I don't need a widget or page. I have a module that sends response in XML. Everything is coded, no GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your commitment, but as I stated in question I need to generate a query to grab like 3 items from database ordered by NewsDate desc. I have no problem to grab all the news and order them in memory, however that is bad practice to get all news from database if you need just 3 items. Don't you think so?

Comment: Frankly if you know there are only three and will ever only be three or some similarly small number, go for it.

Comment: Agree. I usually query if I need to grab a small number of items.